# Timeout exception when try to run karate feature in Gatling

Tags: karate

StackTrace:

```
    12:36:24.036 [main] ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://GatlingSystem/user/gatling-controller#1966422103]] after [2147473647 ms]. Message of type [io.gatling.core.controller.ControllerCommand$Start]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$defaultOnTimeout$1(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:650)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:337)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.$anonfun$close$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:141)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.$anonfun$close$1$adapted(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:140)
```

My feature file contains 7 api endpoint, running them as seperate feature work perfectly but with Gatling its give error.
And I am new to Gatling so unable identify the cause. 
below is my .scala file looks like

```
 val protocol: KarateProtocol = karateProtocol(
    "/billingAccounts/summaries" -> pauseFor("get" -> 15),
    "/billingMonths" -> Nil,
    "/billingAccounts" -> Nil)

  val customerProtocol: KarateProtocol = karateProtocol(
    "/customerBills/unpaid" -> Nil,
    "/customerBills/paid/{year}/{month}" -> Nil,
    "customerBills/paymentOrders?billId={id}" -> Nil,
    "/customerBills/processing" -> Nil)
  val billing: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("CustomerBill").exec(karateFeature("classpath:bff/customerBill/CustomerBill.feature"))

  val customerBill: ScenarioBuilder = scenario(scenarioName = "billing").exec(karateFeature("classpath:bff/customerBill/CustomerBill.feature"))
  setUp(
    billing.inject(rampUsers(10) during (60 seconds)).protocols(protocol),
    customerBill.inject(rampUsers(10) during (60 seconds)).protocols(customerProtocol)

  )

after(
  Thread.sleep(1000)
)
```

Is anyone idea what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Please refer this issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/845 and try version 0.9.5.RC1 Follow the instructions carefully and if you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue